# Etymology of "duck"

Tags: etymology, latin, old-english, animals

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=duck) and [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duce#Old_English) don't seem to agree on that one.

Many European languages have cognates (*Ente, anatra, eend*), but *duck* seems isolated.  Where does English take *duck* from?

**Edit**
As Henry has pointed out, the etymologies of etymonline and wiktionary are actually consistent. See comments.

Comment: "wikitionary" means nothing, it's not a reference just a chat site. but you seem to be looking at the wrong page "duce" rather than "duck"....?

Comment: @Joe, If you have [looked up *duck* in wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/duck#Etymology_1) you have probably noticed that the first etymology section points at the *Old English* word *duce* /ˈdʊke/ (and I don't quite share your rating of wiktionary).

Comment: They are consistent, though Etymonline is fuller, both pointing at *duce*.  It seems the bird name comes from the action, and the action has germanic cognates.

Comment: @Henry, except that the *duce* of wiktionary says "From Latin dūcere, present active infinitive of dūcō" and *that* ducere is to *lead* rather than to *dive*.  I discovered that only after a while.

Comment: @Alan: That is for the Italian/Latin/Romanian *duce* related to *Duke*, not the Old English *duce* related to *duck*.

Comment: @Henry, thank you so much. That's right! So yes it's all consistent then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the wikipedia page for the animal:

> The word duck comes from Old English *dūce "diver", a derivative of the verb *dūcan "to duck, bend down low as if to get under something, or dive", because of the way many species in the dabbling duck group feed by upending; compare with Dutch duiken and German tauchen "to dive".
>
> This word replaced Old English ened/ænid "duck", possibly to avoid confusion with other Old English words, like ende "end" with similar forms. Other Germanic languages still have similar words for "duck", for example, Dutch eend "duck" and German Ente "duck". The word ened/ænid was inherited from Proto-Indo-European; compare: Latin anas "duck", Lithuanian ántis "duck", Ancient Greek nēssa/nētta (νήσσα, νήττα) "duck", and Sanskrit ātí "water bird", among others.